# Зачем Image Assets в Android Studio создает иконки "name"-web.png?

Tags: android, java, android-studio

При создании картинки через image assets в android studio создается несколько вариантов картинок, с разными разрешениями и в разные папки. Всё что создается в drawable-xxx всё ясно, но почему то создается еще 1 вариант, который называется немного по другому, к названию картинки добавляется -web, а её местоположением является пакет main, то есть они даже лежат не в main/res/, а просто в main/, рядом с AndroidManifest.xml.

Может кто подскажет, для каких случаев они нужны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Она нужна для play.google.com. Когда нужно будет залить приложение, нужно также добавить иконку, которая будет показываться на десктопах при входе в маркет.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta вот например иконка хрома слева